# Oracle AS keyword and subqueries

Tags: sql, oracle, rdbms, rdbms-agnostic

Just found out that Oracle does not like it when you use the `AS` keyword to alias a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM products) AS p
```

I need to keep my SQL queries as portable as possible. Will the removal of the `AS` keyword in the above query affect any other RDBMS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern for the SQL 99 ANSI is that the table can have an alias **WITHOUT** the `AS` keyword so, you can take out `AS` and it should work on every RDBMS. See it on fiddle:

- [MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/26833)
- [Oracle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/21890)
- [PostgreSql](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/561)
- [SQLLite](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/d41d8/905)
- [SQLServer](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/12622)

In [ISO/IEC 9075-2:1999](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~len/sql1999.pdf), section *7.6 <table reference>*, page 232:

```
<table reference> ::=
   <table primary>
   | <joined table>

<table primary> ::=
   <table or query name> [ [ AS ] <correlation name>
      [ <left paren> <derived column list> <right paren> ] ]
   | <derived table> [ AS ] <correlation name>
      [ <left paren> <derived column list> <right paren> ]
   | <lateral derived table> [ AS ] <correlation name>
      [ <left paren> <derived column list> <right paren> ]
   | <collection derived table> [ AS ] <correlation name>
      [ <left paren> <derived column list> <right paren> ]
   | <only spec>
      [ [ AS ] <correlation name>
         [ <left paren> <derived column list> <right paren> ] ]
   | <left paren> <joined table> <right paren>
```

---

Also confirmed to work:

- MS Access (Jet)

Comment: I know MySQL requires an alias, my question was about the usage of the `AS` keyword.

Comment: Thanks. A link, or a quote, from the standard you are referring to would be very valuable.

Comment: It wouldn't mean anything in terms of RDBMS compliance though

Comment: @MaxToro I put a link to a PDF document. But as DavidAldridge said, 'it wouldn't mean anything in terms of RDBMS'

Comment: @MaxToro I know that has been some time since this question, did it solve your problem? If yes, please consider in accepting it :)